# Console log with color doesn't wrap first line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When using a console log with color which is long enough, the line is not wrapped.

Im using chrome as my browser.

```js
console.log('%c' + "Really long line                                                                           ", "color:red")
```

[image]

vs without color

```js
console.log("Really long line                                                                           ")
```

[image]

Is it possible to change this behavior ?

Comment: What browser do you use? I can't reproduce this (or I don't understand the problem).

Comment: I use chrome, I put it in the tags

Comment: It seems like a Chromium specific problem. Maybe a bug in the console.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too. Also I didn't find any documentation of this behavior.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). You could open a new issue if you don't find anything similar.